# Lagrangian density for General Relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, variational-principle, variational-calculus

Walter Thirring in his book proposes lagrangian density 
$$\mathcal L = -\frac{1}{2} J \wedge \star J -\frac{1}{2}F \wedge \star F+\frac{1}{16 \pi G}R_{\alpha \beta}\wedge \star e^{\alpha \beta},$$ where $F=\mbox dA,\ J=\mbox dS+eA$, and $R_{\alpha \beta}$ are curvature forms, defines functional $W=\int_M \mathcal L$ and variates this functional to derive Einstein field equation. Alas he doesn't write what he is doing precisely. I suppose we vary this functional with respect to $S$ and $e^\alpha,\ \alpha=0,1,2,3$. Am I right?

Comment: BTW, what is $S$ ? And what result does he obtain after the variation ?

Comment: I would guess that $d L$ would represent the Einstein equations being $d (dA) = 0$ and $d (dS)=0$, and the variation of $e$ in $J$ being compensated for the variation of $e$ in $R$-term. Just guessing though...

Comment: $S$ is $0$-form (real-valued function). He calls it "superpotential". He obtaines $$\delta \mathcal L=\delta S \mbox d\star J-\delta A\wedge (\mbox d \star F+e \star J )+\delta e^\alpha \wedge (\star t_\alpha +\star T_\alpha +\frac{1}{16\pi G}\star e_{\alpha \beta \gamma }\wedge R^{\beta \gamma})-\mathrm{exact\ form},$$ where $$\star t_\alpha =\frac{1}{2}(i_\alpha J \star J+J \wedge i_\alpha \star J ),\ \star T_\alpha =\frac{1}{2}(i_\alpha F\wedge \star F-F \wedge i_\alpha \star F)$$ ($t_\alpha$ and $T_\alpha$) are energy-momentum $1$-forms.

Comment: He acts as though $A$ and $e^\alpha$ were independent and variates them independently, but it doesn't make sense for me, since $A=A_\alpha e^\alpha$ hence variation of $e^\alpha$ changes $A$. In my opinion $\delta A$ should be equal to $A_\alpha \delta e^\alpha$ i.e. $$\delta A=\delta(A_\alpha e^\alpha) = A_\alpha \delta e^\alpha.$$ Am I right?

Comment: The Lagrangian looks like a Einstein gravity with a scalar field coupled to a vector, except I presume J should be dS+eSA. Do you want people to answer the equations of motion or explain what each term means?